# How to display input completion for literal type in python on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, type-hinting

Please let me know if there is a way to display input completion for Literal type in .py code or .ipynb code (jupyter) on vscode.
(e.g., putting in extensions, etc.)

As shown in the figure below, when a specific string is defined as a type in typescript, input completion of the string is recommented with the argument with that type specification, etc.
Please let me know if there is a way to realize a similar input completion function in python.

[Example of input completion in typescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my715.png)

[Example of no input completion in jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H6Ja.png)

Search for the appropriate extension

Comment: you can always create a pull request for PyLance that adds this code analysis and suggestions